# PHP - cannot access to varible in included file

Tags: php

I have problems with accessing array in included file. Code works only when I directly include en.php. Mayby I cannot access to array words because en.php is "sub-included"?

> index.php

```
<?php
include 'localization/langSwitcher.php';
echo $words['title'];
```

> langSwitcher.php

```
<?php

function SetLanguage()
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE['lang']))
    {
        switch ($_COOKIE['lang']) {
            case 'en':
                include 'localization/en.php';
                break;

            default:
                include 'localization/en.php';
                setcookie('lang', 'en', time() + 365 * 24 * 3600, '/');
                break;
        }
    }
    else
        setcookie('lang', 'en', time() + 365 * 24 * 3600, '/');
}

SetLanguage();
```

> en.php

```
<?php
$words = array(
    'title' => 'Welcome on Trex where you can buy or sell via Internet!', 
    '' => ''
);
```

Comment: It'll be a scope issue. You're setting up `$words` inside a function, and it's not accessible from outside that function - you'll have to either use a global, or return `$words` from your function instead

Answer (score 2):

As file included within a function - all variables in this function are not available outside function.

So you should use `global` keyword for example:

```
$words = array();
function SetLanguage()
{
    global $words;   // here

    if(isset($_COOKIE['lang']))
    {
        switch ($_COOKIE['lang']) {
            case 'en':
                include 'localization/en.php';
                break;

            default:
                include 'localization/en.php';
                setcookie('lang', 'en', time() + 365 * 24 * 3600, '/');
                break;
        }
    }
    else
        setcookie('lang', 'en', time() + 365 * 24 * 3600, '/');
}

SetLanguage();
```

Or your function can return `$words` a result of it's execution.

Comment: Indeed, you beat me to it by 46 seconds :)